# What is the difference between "object-fit: contain" and "max-width: 100%;max-height:100%"?

Tags: html, css

I was using "object-fit: contain" to scale an Image when I realised that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer / Edge. So I switched to "max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;" and I was wondering where the difference is?

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I am a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

max-width and max-height property stop your image to go outside of container If you apply both property max-width:100% and max-height:100% then image will show in without stretching and within the container.

object-fit:contain :-

With object-fit contain you have to define your image height width otherwise it will go outside of container.

Using the object-fit property, you can fit the contents of an image into the dimensions you specify in your style sheet.
The contain value tells the image to shrink or enlarge itself until it fits in the box while maintaining its aspect-ratio.

```css
.first-item {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.second-item {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.first-item img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.second-item img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-item">
  <img src="http://perform-ers.com/images/channel/logo/8f4beb43c0b80dd46228cb87364f4196.jpg" class="grid-img">
</div>
<div class="second-item">
  <img src="http://perform-ers.com/images/channel/logo/8f4beb43c0b80dd46228cb87364f4196.jpg" class="grid-img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It behaves similarly as background images:

`contain` should fit the image into the container so that the *whole* image will be visible and that it keeps its original proportion between width and height. Depending on the proportions of the container  this can result in 100% width *or* 100% height, with the other parameter being set to auto.

`width: 100%; height: 100%` will in most cases distort the image: It will show the whole image (without cutting off anything), but it will stretch both parameters independently. Think of a 200x200px image that is put into a 400x600 container: The width will be strechted to twice the original, while the height will be stretched to three times the orignal height - this will result in an ugly distortion.

If `object-fit: contain` is applied to the same example (*instead* of `width: 100%; height: 100%`), the new img width will be 400px (= doubled), and the height will also be 400px, since the proportion is kept, resulting in some empty space, but also in a *not* distorted image.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because it's not supported by IE / Edge.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Answer (score 0):

As far as layout is concerned:

If the element has a locked aspect ratio, `"max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%"` will behave like `object-fit: scale-down`

`object-fit: contain` guarantees that one of the dimensions of the object will match its container. In some cases, this will look like you had written just `"width: 100%"` and in others just `"height: 100%"` depending on the relative aspect ratios of the object and container.

Also...
`object-fit` is specifically for [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) and won't work on most html elements. It does not size an HTML element but an internal object. The image of an `<img>` will be resized but not the `<img>` itself